# MySQL - Select and Join and Rename Columns

Tags: mysql

**I have three tables, two of which are in the master_biz database, and the third is in that master_custom database.**

**master_biz.legend_asset Table**

```html
<style type="text/css">
  table.tableizer-table {
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  .tableizer-table td {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
  }
  .tableizer-table th {
    background-color: #104E8B;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
      <th>id</th>
      <th>did</th>
      <th>roa_id</th>
      <th>make</th>
      <th>model</th>
      <th>type</th>
      <th>function</th>
      <th>status</th>
      <th>owner</th>
      <th>serial</th>
      <th>asset_tag</th>
      <th>rfid</th>
      <th>date_edit</th>
      <th>user_edit</th>
      <th>a_notes</th>
      <th>owner_admin</th>
      <th>owner_tech</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Tenable</td>
      <td>Nessus</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Unknown</td>
      <td>Production</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>5/23/2016 16:19</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Tenable</td>
      <td>Nessus</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Unknown</td>
      <td>Production</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>5/20/2016 18:59</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Microsoft</td>
      <td>Windows Server Standard 2012 R2</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Unknown</td>
      <td>Production</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>5/20/2016 18:59</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Solarwinds</td>
      <td>Kiwi CAT Tools</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Unknown</td>
      <td>Production</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>5/20/2016 18:59</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Splunk</td>
      <td>Enterprise</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Unknown</td>
      <td>Production</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>5/20/2016 18:59</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Splunk</td>
      <td>Enterprise Support</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Unknown</td>
      <td>Production</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>5/23/2016 16:19</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>VMware</td>
      <td>vSphere 5/6 Support Standard</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Unknown</td>
      <td>Production</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>5/20/2016 18:59</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>VMware</td>
      <td>vSphere 5/6 Support Enterprise Plus</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Unknown</td>
      <td>Production</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>5/20/2016 18:59</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>VMware</td>
      <td>vCenter 5/6 Support Standard</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Unknown</td>
      <td>Production</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>5/20/2016 18:59</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**master_biz.asset_location Table**

```html
<style type="text/css">
  table.tableizer-table {
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  .tableizer-table td {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
  }
  .tableizer-table th {
    background-color: #104E8B;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
      <th>iid</th>
      <th>location</th>
      <th>floor</th>
      <th>room</th>
      <th>plate</th>
      <th>panel</th>
      <th>punch</th>
      <th>zone</th>
      <th>rack</th>
      <th>shelf</th>
      <th>date_edit</th>
      <th>user_edit</th>
      <th>l_notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Lab</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Production</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**master_custom.custom_app_table_4 Table**

```html
<style type="text/css">
  table.tableizer-table {
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  .tableizer-table td {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
  }
  .tableizer-table th {
    background-color: #104E8B;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
      <th>id</th>
      <th>2_2</th>
      <th>8_2</th>
      <th>9_2</th>
      <th>10_2</th>
      <th>11_2</th>
      <th>12_2</th>
      <th>13_2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Software License</td>
      <td>Tenable</td>
      <td>Professional</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>5/10/2017</td>
      <td>2190</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Software License</td>
      <td>Tenable</td>
      <td>Professional</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>5/10/2017</td>
      <td>2190</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Software License</td>
      <td>Microsoft</td>
      <td>Standard</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>5/3/2016</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Software Maintenance</td>
      <td>Solarwinds</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>10/30/2016</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Software License</td>
      <td>Splunk</td>
      <td>20GB</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>6/1/2016</td>
      <td>60000</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Software Maintenance</td>
      <td>Splunk</td>
      <td>Enterprise</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>6/1/2016</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Software Maintenance</td>
      <td>VMware</td>
      <td>24x7 Production</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>5/10/2017</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Software Maintenance</td>
      <td>VMware</td>
      <td>Subscription Only</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>5/10/2017</td>
      <td>4375</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Software Maintenance</td>
      <td>VMware</td>
      <td>Subscription Only</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>5/10/2017</td>
      <td>530</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**I am currently using the following code to join two of these tables.** 
This code works, but I am left with a lot of extra columns and column names that do not accurately represent the data.

```
SELECT *
FROM master_biz.legend_asset
RIGHT JOIN master_custom.custom_app_table_4 
  USING (id);
```

**I would like to join all three of these tables using the `id` columns and the `iid` column. I also need to have the ability to select only the columns that I require.**

**How I think it should be done:**

```
SELECT
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.ID AS ASSET_ID,
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.2_2 AS CONTRACT_TYPE,
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.8_2 AS SUPPLIER,
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.9_2 AS SUPPORT_LEVEL,
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.10_2 AS QUANTITY,
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.11_2 AS LICENSE_EXPIRATION,
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.12_2 AS LICENSE_COST,
 master_biz.legend_asset.roa_id AS ORGANIZATION_NUMBER,
 master_biz.legend_asset.make AS MANUFACTURER,
 master_biz.legend_asset.model AS PRODUCT,
 master_biz.legend_asset.status AS STATUS
FROM
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4,
 master_biz.legend_asset
Left JOIN
 master_biz.legend_asset
ON
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.ASSET_ID=master_biz.legend_asset.ID
```

**Error code received when executed:**

`#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'legend_asset'`

If anyone has an idea of how this can be accomplished, and are willing to share, it would be greatly appreciated.

My original post was here:
[MySQL and Splunk - Select and Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445169/mysql-and-splunk-select-and-join)
Being that the main issue was resolved, I felt it was appropriate to create another question to keep that one less busy for future help-seekers.

Comment: I see how my proposed way of doing this is failing.  I still am not familiar with a way of accomplishing my goals. "I would like to join all three of these tables using the `id` columns and the `iid`column. I also need to have the ability to select only the columns that I require."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you joined on the "master_biz.legend_asset" table twice. You would need to provide an Alias for each to make this work (see mbla1 and mbla2 below). You'd also need to use those Aliases for each column in your Select Clause.

```
SELECT
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.ID AS ASSET_ID,
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.2_2 AS CONTRACT_TYPE,
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.8_2 AS SUPPLIER,
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.9_2 AS SUPPORT_LEVEL,
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.10_2 AS QUANTITY,
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.11_2 AS LICENSE_EXPIRATION,
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.12_2 AS LICENSE_COST,
 mbla1.roa_id AS ORGANIZATION_NUMBER,   --Aliased column
 mbla1.make AS MANUFACTURER,            --Aliased column
 mbla2.model AS PRODUCT,                --Aliased column
 mbla2.status AS STATUS                  --Aliased column
FROM
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4,
 master_biz.legend_asset mbla1          --Aliased table
Left JOIN
 master_biz.legend_asset mbla2          --Aliased table
ON
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4.ASSET_ID=master_biz.legend_asset.ID
```

Comment: I tried this to no avail. I corrected the missing "." in `mbla2status AS STATUS `. Whne I executed the query I get the following error:

    `#1054 - Unknown column`
`
`
`master_custom.custom_app_table_4.ASSET_ID' in on clause`

Comment: Changing ` 
`
`
`master_custom.custom_app_table_4.ASSET_ID=master_biz.legend_asset.ID` to ` 
`
`
`master_custom.custom_app_table_4.ID=master_biz.legend_asset.ID`
results in the same `#1054 - Unknown column 'master_custom.custom_app_table_4.ID' in 'on clause' ` error.

Comment: Sorry for the error on mbla2.status; I have since corrected it. With regard to the issue in your 'on' clause, you might try Aliasing the "master_custom.custom_app_table_4" Table in your 'From' clause and use the same Alias (instead of the table name) in the 'On' clause.

Comment: I am not worried about the mistake. I was only pointing it out in case someone comes back later trying to use this answer. With some tweaking I was able to get this to work. I guess I was just having an off day, because I came in and reread everything and it clicked. The code I ended up using was:

Comment: SELECT 
     master_biz.legend_asset.roa_id AS ORGANIZATION_NUMBER,
     master_biz.legend_asset.make AS MANUFACTURER,
     master_biz.legend_asset.model AS PRODUCT,
     master_biz.legend_asset.status AS STATUS,
     master_custom.custom_app_table_4.ID AS ASSET_ID,
     master_custom.custom_app_table_4.2_2 AS CONTRACT_TYPE,
     master_custom.custom_app_table_4.8_2 AS SUPPLIER,
     master_custom.custom_app_table_4.9_2 AS SUPPORT_LEVEL
    FROM master_biz.legend_asset
    LEFT JOIN master_custom.custom_app_table_4 
      USING (id);

Comment: Thanks @TWD for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're loading the same table twice:

```
FROM
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4,
 master_biz.legend_asset    <---#1
Left JOIN
 master_biz.legend_asset    <---#2
```

at least one those two mentions of the table has to be aliased away to a unique name, e.g:

```
FROM
 master_custom.custom_app_table_4,
 master_biz.legend_asset   AS foo
Left JOIN
 master_biz.legend_asset   AS bar
```

then use `foo` and `bar` everywhere else in your query as appropriate.